Convergence of a sequence of power series defined in a different way
We say that a sequence of formal power series $(f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots)$ converges to $f(x)$ if, for all $n$, there exists an $N$ where $[x^n]f_i(x)=[x^n]f(x)$ for all $i\geq N$.
I am wondering about power series $(g_1(x),g_2(x),\ldots)$ that "converge" to $g(x)$ in the sense that, for all $n$, we have $\lim_{i\to\infty}[x^n]g_i(x)=[x^n]g(x)$. These are not the same thing, for example the sequence defined by $$g_i(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{i-1}{i}x^n$$ converges to $$g(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}x^n$$ in the second sense, but not the regular sense.
Is there a term for sequences like these? Are they studied or do they have a use?

This is the topology of coefficientwise convergence which is induced by the metric given by
$$d(f,g):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-i}\frac{\vert a_i-b_i\vert}{1+\vert a_i-b_i\vert}
$$
where $a_i=[x^i]f(x)$ and $b_i=[x^i]g(x)$.

Thank you! This is interesting.
